# Dual monitor PDF opens between the monitors (18.04 Gnome)

Tags: multiple-monitors, pdf, window

A new PDF file always opens halfway between two monitors. How can I solve this?

Using 18.04 LTS, Xorg and/or Wayland, Communitheme.